# python : object() takes no parameter

Tags: python

When I run the files from the book download, then it works, but when I type the code myself, then I get an error.

File **cat2.py**

```
class Cat:
    # constructor:
    def _init_(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def speak(self):
        print(self.name, "says Meow")

    def drink(self):
        print(self.name, "drinks some milk.")
        print(self.name, "takes a nap.")
```

File **main2.py**

```
import cat2

#create two instances of a cat
romeo = cat2.Cat("Romeo")
juliet = cat2.Cat("Juliet")

# play with Romeo
romeo.speak()
romeo.drink()

# play with Juliet
juliet.speak()
juliet.drink()
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Object() takes no parameters.
```

Comment: I download author files, it works.  BUT I type, CANNOT RUN??

Comment: `__init__` instead of `_init_`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the class constructor, you need to change your method name from `_init_()` to `__init__()`; it needs double underscores on each side.

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

In the code you show, the method `_init_()` (with only 1 underscore on each side) does **NOT** override the class constructor. The error you get is because the line `romeo = cat2.Cat("Romeo")` passes an argument to the constructor of `Cat`, but the original constructor does not take any additional arguments.